# importing googleapis in Nodejs gives error. How to properly import googleapis pakage.Iam using type:modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-api, nodemailer

Following is my imports and google OAuth2 config. But it gives error as:
ReferenceError: OAuth is not defined

```js
import google from "googleapis";
let OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_ID,
  MAILING_SERVICE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  MAILING_SERVICE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
  SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
  OAUTH_PLAYGROUND
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `"type": "module"` in package.json do like this:

```
import {google} from "googleapis";
```

else

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");
```

Comment: GIves SyntaxError: the requested module 'googleapis' is expected to be of type CommonJs ,which does not support named export. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export. Fro example:import pkg from 'googleapis'; const {google} = pkg @Mohammad Yaser

Comment: but iam using type:modules....so using require() gives error that require is not defined @Mohammad Yaser